# How to change color of HTML list item (color:firebrick is not working

Tags: html, css

I've tried the obvious approach of trying color:firebrick in everything I could think of, as you'll see in the css link. This is the only thing google says to do. I had it working a bunch of edits ago before making my list inline, but figured it would be an easy fix as it was easy to do in the first place.

I hope asking "whats wrong with my code" isn't too situation specific for the guidelines, but I'm stumped.

I know the title appears to be an easily googled, repeat question. But nothing I have researched has solved it.

I need it to look like this:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```css
#headings {
  background-color: firebrick;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#headings h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2 {
  color: thistle;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#nav {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: firebrick;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav ul {
  color: firebrick;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav li {
  color: firebrick;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-left: 4%;
}

#content {
  padding: 2em;
}

.figure {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 40px;
  clear: both;
  padding: 1em;
}

.equation {
  text-align: center;
}

#footnotes {
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding: 3em;
}

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HW2.css" />
  <title>Math 300 Assignment 2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="headings">
    <h1>A Mathematical Web</h1>
    <h2>Roots of Polynomials</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://math.wsu.edu/kcooper/M300/HWpoly_home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://math.wsu.edu/kcooper/M300/HWpoly_quadratic.html">The Quadratic</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://math.wsu.edu/kcooper/M300/HWpoly_cubic.html">The Cubic</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://math.wsu.edu/kcooper/M300/HWpoly_quartic.html">The Quartic</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://math.wsu.edu/kcooper/M300/HWpoly_galois.html">Galois Theory</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h1>The Quadratic</h1>
    <p>
      A polynomial of degree two is called a quadratic, and an equation involving a quadratic polynomial whose value is zero is called a quadratic equation. The solutions of a quadratic equation are called the <i>roots</i> of the polynomial. Figure 1
      shows the graph of a quadratic polynomial. The roots of the polynomial are the points where the graph crosses the <i>x</i>-axis.
    </p>
    <div class="figure">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Polynomialdeg2.svg"> Figure 1. A quadratic polynomial<sup>*</sup>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <p>
      The means of finding the roots of quadratic polynomials were known to the Babylonians and others thousands of years ago. Today, we can write our solutions more elegantly using modern mathematical notation. A general quadratic polynomial can be written
      in the form
    </p>
    <p class="equation">
      p(x) = ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c.
    </p>
    <p>
      Using this notation, we can write the roots of <i>p</i> as
    </p>
    <p class="equation">
      ( 1/(2a) ) ( -b ± [ b<sup>2</sup> - 4ac ]<sup>1/2</sup> ).
    </p>
    <p>
      We can see that whenever <span class="equation">b<sup>2</sup> - 4ac &lt; 0</span> then there are two complex roots with non-zero imaginary parts. If
      <span class="equation">b<sup>2</sup> - 4ac = 0</span> then there is exactly one root, which is real. Otherwise, there are two real roots.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="footnotes">
    * By Original hand-drawn version: N.Mori Updated hand-drawn version: Rubber Duck (☮ • ✍) [Public domain], via Wikimedia Commons
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Copyright © 2018 Kevin Cooper
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: post your code in snippet please

Comment: Will do next time, thanks for editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Add Color to `#nav li a` not `#nav li`

```
  #nav li a{
    color: firebrick;
    text-decoration: none;

  }
  #nav li
  {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 4%;
  }
```

Comment: was the "a" because I was changing a link and not just text? And it worked, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the `a` color so use:

```
li a{
    color: firebrick;
}
```

To remove the line under text use to `li a` css:

```
text-decoration: none;
```